# Is it possible to have a separate hover effect for an li element in a nested list?

Tags: html, css

For the following code:

html

```
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="collapsible">
        <i class="fas"></i><a href="#">item 1 </a>
        <ul class="collapsible__content">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">item 2 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

If I use

css

```
.menu li:hover,
.menu li ul li:hover, {
background: some color;
}
```

the whole parent list will have the same color when I hover over a child. But if I only use

```
.menu li ul li:hover, {
background: some color;
}
```

the other li elements cannot get the hover effect.

How to solve this problem? If JavaScript helps that's good too.

Comment: One easy solution cloud be give a class name to the second <li>

Answer (score 0):

Anything like that?
There is an error in the code you put, the comma at the end of `.menu li ul li:hover`

```css
.menu li:hover {
background: red;
}

.menu li ul li:hover {
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="collapsible">
        <a href="#">item 1 </a>
        <ul class="collapsible__content">
          <li><a href="#">item 2 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to delete the comma when I deleted another class so that this looks simpler... Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu li > :not(ul):hover {

}
```

should work if your `li` can have at most 1 `ul` and 1 none `ul` element